# How can I update Drupal core and all modules / themes in one go from the command line?

Tags: 8, updating

On a LAMP environment, I have a Drupal site which uses the default theme and a few stable contributed modules. Nothing is customized, and I have daily backups so I don't "fear" of updating.

How could I update core, modules, and themes in one go from the command line when `drush up` no longer is an option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you are using Composer to maintain your Drupal 8 installation, you can use the following command to update core and all modules (and dependencies).

```bash
composer update drupal/* --with-dependencies
```

If you started the project from [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project), the command becomes the following.

```bash
composer update drupal/* webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies
```

I recommend reading [Updating Drupal core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer) and [Updating Modules and Themes using Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-modules).

After updating, don't forget to run the updates and rebuild the cache.

```bash
drush updatedb
drush cache:rebuild
```

If you started the project from *drupal/drupal* as the user guide says, [you are in trouble](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#download-core-option-c), since *drupal/core* isn't listed as installed. You could try to use [Composerize Drupal](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal) to fix the problem.
If you started your project from a tar-ball, you also need use [Composerize Drupal](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal) if you don't plan to manually update forever.

Drush 9 and later doesn't support updating core or modules. It will tell you to use Composer. Reading the [Drush docs](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/) is very useful.

Comment: I belive this should be updated for project that use drupal/core-recommended

Comment: Maybe, but I thought the difference in commands only appear if you try to update Drupal core separately? This questions is about updating everything in one go. I don't have time to test. If you verify that a different command is needed, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using Composer as described in [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies), it's three steps.

```bash
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
drush updb -y
drush cr
```

See also [Updating Drupal core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer) for more details.